# Error when typing left square bracket '[' in Vim insert mode on large markdown files with syntax highlighting turned on

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-plugin

I have encountered a recurrent problem when using Vim with syntax highlighting. The setup is simple: have syntax highlighting on (`syntax on`) and open a really long (it has to be quite a lot of text, not sure how long, but enough to exceed their pattern bugger) .markdown or .md file.

Now, whenever I type a left square bracket `[` in insert mode, two things happen:

1. For the first time I do this after opening the file, I get two error messages:

```
E363: Pattern uses more memory than 'maxmempattern'
```

```
Error detected while processing CursorMovedI Autocommands for "*"..function <SNR>18_Highlight_Matching_Pair[135]..CursorMovedI Autocommands
 for "*"..function <SNR>18_Highlight_Matching_Pair:
```

2. The cursor does not move, but the `[` character shows up right underneath the cursor and I cannot insert to the right of the `[`. I tried right arrow in Insert mode or A in Normal mode, but could not move the cursor to the right of the `[` character. This problem does not show up with `]` or the left side of other brackets like `{` or `(`.

Of course, I could turn off the syntax highlighting function, but I would like to see if there is a way to keep syntax highlighting while preventing this problem. This problem shows up quite consistently, so it would be great to figure out a way to fix it or around it.

I have Vim 9.0 if that gives any clues.

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 2):

**In general…**

Runtime scripts are sourced in a specific order, which can be inspected with `:help :scriptnames`. The `<SNR>18` in a stack trace refers to script number 18 in the output of `:scriptnames`.

That information is precious for debugging because it helps answering core questions like "Is it a Vim issue?", "Is it a third-party plugin issue?", and "Is it a *me* issue?".

**In this case…**

The error happens `$VIMRUNTIME/plugin/matchparen.vim`, which is a built-in script.

A quick workaround would be to do:

```
:NoMatchParen
```

as per `:help matchparen`.

A more permanent workaround would be to disable the script in your `vimrc`:

```
let loaded_matchparen = 1
```

But it would be more constructive to open an issue in [Vim's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).

Comment: Thank you for the insights. I submitted it as a Vim issue here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/11355

Comment: On a separate note, the script was indeed matchparen.vim on my machine as well. Still, neither `:NoMatchParen` nor `let loaded_matchparen = 1` in .vimrc worked.